# Declaring a new SerialPort as a variable doesn't allow me to read data? SerialPort node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, serial-port, node-serialport

### What am I trying to do?

For my electron project I am trying to declare my port as a variable so that the path can be changed by the user if necessary. (Need this functionality)

I did see the port.update() function in the documentation but I couldn't get it working for updating the path. Just trying to figure out a way of dynamically updating the port path while still be able to receive incoming data.

### What's my problem?

I have a parser that listens for incoming data from the micro-controller but when I declare the port as a variable it doesn't receive any incoming data. If I declare the port as a constant, the parser is able to read incoming data no problem.

### Code

#### Declaring as variable

```
// where arg is the com specified by the user, I tried it with COM4 but still doesn't work
var port = new SerialPort(arg, {
    baudRate: 115200,
    autoOpen:false
})
```

#### Declaring as constant

```
const port = new SerialPort("COM4",{
    autoOpen:false,
    baudRate:115200
});
```

#### Parser listener

```
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const parse = port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' }));
parse.on('data',function(data){console.log(data)})
```

#### console output for port declared as variable

```
is port open => true
message written
```

#### console output for port declared as const

```
is port open => true
message written
Hello from Micro-controller
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing may be due to the timing of when the port is opened. In the code where the port is declared as a variable, it's using autoOpen: false, which means the port is not automatically opened. You need to open the port manually by calling port.open() before you start listening for incoming data. Here's how you can do it:

```js
var port = new SerialPort(arg, {
    baudRate: 115200,
    autoOpen: false
});

port.open(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Error opening port: ', err.message);
    }

    const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
    const parse = port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' }));
    parse.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

By manually opening the port after its creation, you should be able to change the path dynamically as needed and still receive incoming data.

In the code where the port is declared as a constant, it works because the port is automatically opened at the time of creation, which is why the parser can read incoming data.

To summarize, when using a variable for the port, you need to explicitly open it before setting up the parser to receive incoming data.